# Creating a ruby IO object from request.body.read?

Tags: ruby, io, sinatra, xmlhttprequest

I'm using sinatra and transloadit and sending files with xhr using valumns file uploader.

I need to create a IO object and fill it with data in request.body.read

How can I do that ? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `StringIO`:

```
require 'stringio'
StringIO.new(request.body.read)
```

Alternatively, can't you just pass `request.body` for your IO object?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `request.body`, call `request.body.rewind` first.